# relation between gazebo and rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

2-) what is its relation with gazebo and RVIZ ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45791/relation-between-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo is a 3D rigid-body physics simulator (including a graphical interface).

rviz is a tool for 3D visualization of data from other ROS nodes as well as some support for sending commands to other ROS nodes.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-14**:
Does rviz can show me as a simulation what robot thinking about now such as different paths to grasp a cup before actually ground it to robot specific hardware ?!

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-10-14**:
rviz can show you anything that it has a plugin for displaying and has been published by your nodes. You can find a list of DisplayTypes here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-14**:
I mean something such as when infer for missing component can RVIZ show me what the robot think about now , before actually robot move to that object and try to grasp it ?!
like display missing component beside component it really see now but with different colors reflect periorty of this component

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-10-14**:
I'm not 100% sure I get what you're asking. rviz can show you anything you publish that it knows how to show. It does not do any sort of inference on it's own. For example, if you wanted to see N possible plans from a planner at time t, your planning node would have to publish all N plans to rviz.